# How do I convert from unicode to single byte in C#?

Tags: c#, unicode, char

How do I convert from unicode to single byte in C#?

This does not work:

```
int level =1;
string argument;
// and then argument is assigned

if (argument[2] == Convert.ToChar(level))
{
    // does not work
}
```

And this:

```
char test1 = argument[2];
char test2 = Convert.ToChar(level);
```

produces funky results. `test1` can be: ***`49 '1'`*** while `test2` will be ***`1 ''`***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138449/how-to-convert-a-unicode-character-to-its-ascii-equivalent

Comment: Do you want `level` to be converted to the char '1' , or a char with value 1 ? That's the same difference as in doing `char c = '1'` and `char c = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.getbytes.aspx).

```
UnicodeEncoding unicode = new UnicodeEncoding();
Byte[] encodedBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);
```

Answer (score 3):

> How do I convert from unicode to single byte in C#?

This question makes no sense, and the sample code just makes things worse.

Unicode is a mapping from characters to code points. The code points are numbered from 0x0 to 0x10FFFF, which is far more values than can be stored in a single byte.

And the sample code has an `int`, a `string`, and a `char`. There are no `byte`s anywhere.

What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`char` and `string` are always Unicode in .NET. You can't do it the way you're trying.

In fact, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test whether the int *level* matches the char *argument[2]* then use

```
  if (argument[2] == Convert.ToChar(level + (int)'0'))
```