# Converting ê to e and etc in .net c#

Tags: encoding, ascii

I trying to build a lucene analyzer that brings all special characters (like ê), to its non-special form (which is e).

I found the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138449/how-to-convert-a-unicode-character-to-its-ascii-equivalent#141816), but I couldn't create a solution from the answers.

Any help would by greatly appreciated!