# import data from Access to Excel generates Â​ char

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, data-migration

I am importing data from Access to Excel but sometimes Â​ (latin capital letter a with circumflex) character is generating. Anyone has idea why?

thanks

shuvra

Comment: Sounds like it might be a character set problem.

Comment: How are you importing the data?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if these links have the appropriate solution you are searching for:

http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=65605

http://it.w3support.net/index.php?db=so&id=243540

Comment: thanks very much. i find out actually StreamWriter.WriteLine() function is generating  Â caharacter. how can i stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Check [How to convert a Unicode character to its ASCII equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138449/how-to-convert-a-unicode-character-to-its-ascii-equivalent)

fix is going to be explicitly specifying the encoding you are using to convert to and from byte[] values to strings