# StreamWriter.WriteLine() function is generating a "Â" character

Tags: c#, excel, streaming

I am writing some strings in an Excel file. Sometimes the call to the

```
StreamWriter.WriteLine()
```

function unexpectedly creates a "Â" character.

Any idea why?

**Update**

the code:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Create(outFile)); 
string headerline = ""; 
foreach (DataColumn colum in reportContents.Columns) 
{ 
    headerline = headerline + '"' + row[colum].ToString() + '"' + ',';
} 
writer.WriteLine(headerline);
```

the output:
Personal ProtectionÂ |Post-Retirement Savings|Pre-Retirement Pension|Tax & Estate Planning

Expected output: Personal Protection |Post-Retirement Savings|Pre-Retirement Pension|Tax & Estate Planning

I get the solution:
just i need to specify the default the encoding in StreamWriter like as follows and it works.

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Create(outFile), Encoding.Default);

shuvra

Comment: Please show some code. It is probably a matter of the chosen (or default) encoding for the writer.

Comment: Does it happens on specific string? This question is too vague.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138449/how-to-convert-a-unicode-character-to-its-ascii-equivalent - specify your encoding

Answer (score 3):

It isn't actually creating an `Â` character - it's just writing data in a different encoding. If you look at the `StreamWriter` constructor overloads (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) you can indicate which encoding you want the `StreamWriter` to write it's data in.

In case you haven't dealt with encoding before: Joel wrote a good article about it at http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: the code: StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Create(outFile));
string headerline = "";
 headerline = "";
     foreach (DataColumn colum in reportContents.Columns)
     {
      headerline = headerline + '"' + row[colum].ToString() + '"' + ',';
     }
     writer.WriteLine(headerline);

Comment: I am not using any encoding. why this character will appear? the output is: Personal ProtectionÂ |Post-Retirement Savings|Pre-Retirement Pension|Tax & Estate Planning

Comment: @Shuvra I updated your question with the code you posted in this comment. But YOU should have done that.

Comment: Whenever you store text, you are using encoding. I really suggest reading Joel's post I linked, to rid of this illusion for good.

Comment: I get the solution:
just i need to specify the default the encoding in StreamWriter like as follows and it works.

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Create(outFile), Encoding.Default);


shuvra

Answer (score 1):

The character set of your code should be "utf-8".