# How can I "flatten" text that contains macrons and umlauts in .NET?

Tags: .net, text, unicode, diacritics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a Unicode character to its ASCII equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138449/how-to-convert-a-unicode-character-to-its-ascii-equivalent)
>   [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)

I need to make a search form insensitive to text that contains macrons, umlauts, etc.

For example, "ŌōṒṓṐṑȪȫ" should be considered equal to "oooooooo".

In TSQL I'm able to get it partially working with:

```
select Cast('ŌōṒṓṐṑȪȫ' as varchar)
```

which returns `Oo??????`. It is smart enough to translate the first two characters to "O" and "o".

I was trying to use this C# code to "flatten" the text but it doesn't work at all. The result is "????????".

```
var text = "ŌōṒṓṐṑȪȫ";
var buffer = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text));

var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
```

Is there a way do this in .NET? I know I could create a map that links characters such as "ŌōṒṓṐṑȪȫ" to "o" and so on for other characters, but I'm hoping there is already a built-in way to do this.

Comment: Just remove the diacritics as shown in the link above, then perform a case insensitive comparison

Comment: @HansPassant - Sweet, the solution in the accepted answer of that question works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do normalization, it is time consuming, and there is something better.

Most string comparison operations have a flavor that takes a CompareOptions.
You can use this for CompareOptions:

```
static_cast<CompareOptions>(CompareOptions::IgnoreCase | CompareOptions::IgnoreNonSpace)
```

See the CompareInfo class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z428sw8.aspx

Comment: Wasn't aware of the overload that took the `CompareOptions` enum. That sure is useful though.

Answer (score 2):

The String class has a set of overloaded Normalize() methods.

Comment: No need to use P/Invoke for this, the .NET framework has all the necessary tools to do it