# Accented characters are not showing properly after copying from a text box

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using below code to copy text from some control.Please note text could be in Spanish or English.Later i am showing it up inside a rich text box.

```
Clipboard.Clear();
MyDocBodyControl.Range.Copy();
html = Convert.ToString(Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html));
```

But when i am displaying them in rich text box,the accented characters are not showing properly.If i am using any other formats like `Text`,then i am getting proper accented characters.But i have to use HTML formats because i have some styles to be added with the copied text.

Any way to show the accented characters properly with HTML data format ?

Comment: try setting the character type to a unicode instead of utf8...

Comment: Hey Michael where i need to set character type ? While converting ?

Answer (score 1):

Set a correct encoding? UTF-8/Unicode/... ?
Also have a look on these topics: [How to convert a Unicode character to its ASCII equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138449/how-to-convert-a-unicode-character-to-its-ascii-equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

**DataFormats.Html** [specification](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) states it's encoded in UTF-8. But there's a bug in .NET 4 Framework and lower, and it actually reads as UTF-8 as **Windows-1252**.

You get allot of wrong encodings, which leading to funny/bad characters such as 
'Å','â€¹','Å’','Å½','Å¡','Å“','Å¾','Å¸','Â','Â¡','Â¢','Â£','Â¤','Â¥','Â¦','Â§','Â¨','Â©'

For example '€' is wrongly encoded as   'â‚¬' in Windows-1252.

Full explanation here at this dedicated website
[Debugging Chart Mapping Windows-1252 Characters to UTF-8 Bytes to Latin-1 Characters](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html)

But by using the [conversions tables](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) you will not loose any UTF-8 characters. You can get the original pristine UTF-8 characters from DataFormats.Html. (Note: Ppm solutions defaults to ASCII on a fail and you loose encoding information!)

Also, Chrome adds Apple-converted-* characters that appear as for example 'Â ' from a clip, but [claim](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5756335865987072) to be removed.

Soln: Create a translation dictionary and search and replace.