# Use powershell to write chars to serial port

Tags: powershell, serial-port

Protocol

```
<STX>COMMAND<ETX><CHEKSUM>
```

a valid command is:

```
.004CT1000A.b
```

with `STX = 0x02, ETX = 0x03, CHECKSUM = 0x0062, COMMAND = 004CT1000A`

I want to send this command with powershell on a windows server to a serial port. However there are data type issues:

```
PS > [Char[]] $request = 0x02,0,0,4,"C","T",1,0,0,0,"A",0x03,0x0062
PS > $port.Write($request)
```

This logs a strange string with whitespace on the left and right of each character:

```
. . . . C T . . . . A . b
```

instead of

```
.004CT1000A.b
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

---

and I tried

```
PS > [Char[]] $request = 0x02,"0","0","4","C","T","1","0","0","0","A",0x03,0x0062
PS > $port.Write($request)
```

which printed the right command but with a lot of whitespaces

```
. 0 0 4 C T 1 0 0 0 A . b
```

.004CT1000A.b is created with:

```
unsigned char checksum = 0x02;  
nrComm1->SendChar(0x02);
while(*TX_String)               
{
    nrComm1->SendChar(*TX_String);
    checksum ^= *TX_String++;       
}
nrComm1->SendChar(0x03);
checksum ^= 0x03;       
nrComm1->SendChar(checksum);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the .Net char object type, which is unicode. You probably want to convert your characters to ascii. Some info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138449/how-to-convert-a-unicode-character-to-its-ascii-equivalent).

Or you could just use the decimal values for your ASCII characters and store it all in a byte array:

`> [Byte[]] $request = 0x02,0,0,4,67,84,1,0,0,0,65,0x03,0x0062`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for me. There are still lots of white spaces in between.
[Byte[]] $request = 0x02,0,0,4,67,84,1,0,0,0,65,0x03,0x0062

My solution is:
$request =[char]2 + "004CT1000A" + [char]3 + [char]62